Js files issue in production mode magento2.4.6-p3
Site is working fine in developer mode but when we put the site in production mode there are different files showing 404 in console and these seems default files of magento but the path of the file they are showing there is no such file even in developer mode.
Some of the error message are :
http://127.0.0.1/magento24/static/frontend/MageTheme/child/en_US/domReady.js 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1/magento24/static/frontend/MageTheme/child/en_US/domReady.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1/magento24/static/frontend/MageTheme/child/en_US/jquery-ui-modules/widget.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

 Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1/magento24/static/frontend/MageTheme/child/en_US/jquery-ui-modules/core.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Refused to execute script from 'http://127.0.0.1/magento24/static/frontend/MageTheme/child/en_US/mageTranslationDictionary.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "domReady", needed by: domReady!_unnormalized2, domReady!_unnormalized3
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1738:36)

JS minify, merge, bundling everything is disabled, Also I have reset all file permissions, Use default htaccess of magento, try using virtual host but the issue is still the same.

did you check this answer?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/375099/issue-with-requirejs-path-in-magento-2-4-7-p2-fresh-setup
This is the similar issue
